# Join Query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning MongoDB and really quite new with NoSQL.
I have 2 collections like this:
Customer:

[image: Customer:]

Account:

[image]

I want to create a join query between customer and account collection by _id in customer collection with cust_id in account collection. I tried with this:

```
db.Customer.aggregate({
    $lookup:{
        from:"Account",
        localField:"_id",
        foreignField:"cust_id",
        as:"customer_account"
}}).pretty()
```

But my "customer_account" return a null array. How I can fix this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `cust_id` field in this `Account` document is in `string` type (As you might see from the double quotes).

You need to change it to the `ObjectId` type. So `cust_id: "5499..."` will become `cust_id: ObjectId("5499...")`